# How to dynamically write a React.useState function so that you can have as many input types you want from a cms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

This is a hypothetical question right now, because I am not sure if my approach is even possible. I have a bunch of input checkbox fields in a form. I am using datoCms. I am thinking that I could use the repeater module to create as many or remove checkbox fields, and give them the same label and name as what I write in a text field in dato as a repeater. Now Dato outputs a graphQL api, that I can query and it would output the repeater fields as an array that I can map over after I query it.

So I will show you my code, and what I think will work, but I just need to be pointed in the right direction, and I can update this question with my attempt, but at this point I don't even know really where to start.

The part that is confusing to me is the `React.useState` how would I dynamically add values to it from a map method.

Ok here is my state code

```
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    package: `${data.datoCmsPricing.title}`,
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    weightLoss:"",
    message: "",
  })

  const onChange = (e) => {

    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox' && !e.target.checked) {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: ''});
    } else {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

 }
```

and here is my form

```
<form onSubmit={submitForm}>
    <h3>Reasons for wanting to train</h3>
    <label>
    Weight Loss
    <input 
    type="checkbox"
    name="weightLoss"
    checked={formState.weightLoss}
    onChange={onChange}
    />
    </label>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now this is what I would propose I do with the form to get as many checkboxes, this is basically sudo code at this point because I think it would break at the `checked` part

```
{data.datoCmsPricing.details.map(detailEntry => { 

    return (



        <label key={detailEntry.id}>
        {detailEntry.reason}
        <input 
        type="checkbox"
        name={detailEntry.reason}
        checked={formState.{detailEntry.reason}}
        onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>

    )

})}
```

**after this I don't know what I would do with state?**

Thank you ahead of time. Link to Repo https://github.com/wispyco/jlfit

Comment: I think you're handling it right, just the checked value would fail in your code. Maybe `checked={formState[detailEntry.reason] ? formState[detailEntry.reason] : false}`. If there's no key found in your state then it would default to a false else it would use whatever is in that key

Comment: but in the `const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({` how would I write that so it was dynamic, I am setting weightLoss there but I want it to add as many or little of these repeaters I add.

Comment: Got it, if your form don't have initial values then you could just initialize your formState with an empty object `const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({});`. You would add the keys and values to the state during onChange

Comment: oh ok I will attempt that and update my question if I get stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`useState` perfectly works for dynamic data. And your code is almost correct.

1. You should add `dataEntries` property to `useState` object

   ```
   const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
     name: "",
     package: `package`,
     email: "",
     subject: "",
     weightLoss:"",
     message: "",
     dataEntries: { 
       '1': { reason: 'reason1', checked: false },
       '2': { reason: 'reason2', checked: false },
       '3': { reason: 'reason3', checked: false },
       '4': { reason: 'reason4', checked: false }, },
     })
   ```

   I've prefilled `dataEtries` with demo data. In real app this data will be fetched from backend.
2. Modify `onChange` to correctly handle `dataEntries` object

   ```
   const onChange = e => {
     let value = undefined;
     if (e.target.type === "checkbox") value = e.target.checked;
     else value = e.target.value;
     setFormState({
       ...formState,
       dataEntries: {
         ...formState.dataEntries,
         [e.target.id]: {
           ...formState.dataEntries[e.target.id],
           [e.target.name]: value
         }
       }
     });
   };
   ```
3. And finally set correct `name` and `id` properties on form controls, so `onChange` can properly update data in state.

   ```
   export const Checkbox = ({ onChange, detailEntry }) => (
     <form>
       <label key={detailEntry.id}>
         {detailEntry.reason}
         <input
           type="checkbox"
           name="checked"
           id={detailEntry.id}
           checked={detailEntry.checked}
           onChange={onChange}
         />
         <input
           id={detailEntry.id}
           name="target weight"
           value={detailEntry["target weight"]}
           onChange={onChange}
         />
       </label>
     </form>
   );
   ```

   I've added additional field "target weight" to showcase how any additional control can be used.

Complete demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamicusestate-qwidz)

Comment: So I am using Gatsby JS so for the dynamic data, it's being populated by graphQL from datoCMS, how would I get the numbers 1,2,3,4. I assume I would do something like this `'1': { reason: {dynamicGraphQL}, checked: false }` but shouldn't this whole thing be wrapped in a map, so It iterates. This is the repo https://github.com/wispyco/jlfit